# Tricky integral involving the gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

Evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^k \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{v+1}2\right)}{\sqrt{v\pi}\,\Gamma\left({\frac v2}\right)} \left(1+\frac{t^2}{v}\right)^{-\frac{v+1}2} dt$$

How would we start solving this integral? Would we use a trigonometric substitution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the CDF at $k$ of a [Student's-$t$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). The answer involves a hypergeometric function. It can be obtained in terms of an incomplete Beta function with $t=\sqrt{v}\tan\theta$ followed by $u=\sin^2\theta$, i.e. $u =\frac{t^2}{v+t^2}$.

Comment: First, eliminate the constant (and hence useless) factor $\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{v+1}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{v \pi} \Gamma \left( \frac{v}{2} \right)}$.  Then for $k >0$ and $v>0$ the integral becomes $$k \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{k^2}{v}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\pi
   } \sqrt{v} \Gamma \left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{v+1}{2}\right)}$$